# Optimizing a loop over dijkstra's path

Tags: python, optimization

I have a grid with concentrations of `biomass` that increases over time. When the concentration gets large enough, it needs to divide and push along the path of least resistance, which I've calculated in `shove_graph` below. I currently use dijkstra's algorithm from scipy.sparse.csgraph to calculate the path. scipy's dijkstra performs wonderfully, and lets me do calculate all of the cells that need updating at once.

My code afterwards, however, is abhorrently slow, I'm guessing because of the constant allocation and deallocation, but I don't really know. The basic idea that I followed was the following:

```
# calculates the distance from each index in update_ix to every other
# grid point. predecessors is an array of indices that can backtrack
# from any given index to the starting point, along the shortest
# path (in my case, path of least resistance)
distances, predecessors = dijkstra(shove_graph, indices=update_ix,
                                    return_predecessors=True)
# NOTE: distances.shape = predecessors.shape = (len(update_ix), len(shove_graph))
# For example, if 4 indices need updating on my 10x10 grid,
# the size of shove_graph is 100 (reshaped to 1 dimension above), and
# len(update_ix) = 4, so distances.shape = (4, 100)


# For each of the cells that need updating, find the empty cell and
# the path that satisfies the smallest distance
for (ix, d, p) in itertools.izip(update_ix, distances, predecessors):
    empty = np.arange(N)[biomass == 0]  # indices of empty cells
    d_empty = d[biomass == 0]  # those distances

    # get the index of the smallest distance, then the whole path
    # note: backwards from scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra
    ind = min(zip(d_empty, empty), key=lambda pair: pair[0])[1]
    path = [ind]
    while ind != ix:
        ind = p[ind]
        path.append(ind)

    # Three different pieces get shoved differently.
    # Age is 'new' for the first cell (=0), otherwise is shoved
    # like everything else
    # Half the first eps and active components get pushed into
    # the second compartment.
    # Each of the rest of the compartments get moved 100% to the
    # next cell along the path.
    ind = ix
    age_ix = age[ix]
    active[ind] = 0.5 * active[ind]
    eps[ind] = 0.5 * eps[ind]
    buffer1['age'] = 0
    buffer1['active'] = active[ind]
    buffer1['eps'] = eps[ind]

    while path != []:
        ind = path.pop()

        buffer2['age'] = age[ind]
        buffer2['active'] = active[ind]
        buffer2['eps'] = eps[ind]

        age[ind] = buffer1['age']
        active[ind] = buffer1['active']
        eps[ind] = buffer1['eps']

        buffer1 = deepcopy(buffer2)
```

This for loop runs VERY slowly for the grid sizes I need, so I'd like to optimize it. Unfortunately, I'm really not sure how I can because of the way the predecessors has to work.

If you have any suggestions for something to look into, I'd appreciate it a lot!